# Bootstrap Table data-url

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using Bootstrap Table (http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html) and Im having trouble "binding" my data to the table using data-url.

Heres my table code:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-side-pagination="server" data-url="<? echo $letServiceHandler->getEmployees($_SESSION['api_key'],2); ?>" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

getEmployee calls my rest webservice which will return a json array which looks like this:

```
[
 {"id":"33","name":"5yhjtyjyas 444","active":"0","user_id":"1","no_of_reports":"0"},
 {"id":"29","name":"AAA","active":"1","user_id":"1","no_of_reports":"0"},
 {"id":"20","name":"aasdasd","active":"1","user_id":"1","no_of_reports":"0"}
]
```

getEmployee looks like this:

```
// Gets employees
public function getEmployees($api_key,$active)
{
    $headers = array('Content-type: application/json','Authorization: '.$api_key,);

    if($active==0)
    {
        $curl = curl_init(GET_ALL_INACTIVE_EMPLOYEES);    
    }
    else if($active==1)
    {
        $curl = curl_init(GET_ALL_ACTIVE_EMPLOYEES);    
    }
    else
    {
        $curl = curl_init(GET_ALL_EMPLOYEES);    
    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api_key);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($curl_response === false) 
    {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }

    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response,true);       

    return json_encode($decoded['employees']);
}
```

Please note that Im decoding the response and then encoding it again selecting only the employees nested array.

I tried "echoing" json_encode($decoded['employees']) out and create a file of the data and put that into a file called data.json and insert that into my data-url. That worked perfectly..

Comment: So far i fixed my problem by putting my getEmplooyees function into a seperate file (getEmployee.php) which does the excact same thing as my previous function except not beeing a php function. This ended up working, but Im still a bit confused what the difference is between, calling a function inside the data-url and putting a link to a file which does the same ??? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After beeing in touch with the developer of the table, i found that my attempt to insert data into the table by setting the data-url to my php function is not the correct way to use this "property".

I need to put my function into a seperate php file in order to get it working, which i did as mentioned in my comment above.

So the solution is:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-side-pagination="server" data-url="getEmployees.php?id=2" data-cache="false" data-height="299">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
        <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
        <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

getEmployee.php will be making the request to my webservice and return the result which is then applied to the table.