# bootstrap table data url populate with php

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bottstrap html table:

```
<table data-toggle="table" data-url="../../scripts/tags/s_displaytags.php"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="TagName" data-sort-order="desc">
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th data-field="SerialNumber" data-sortable="true">Serial #</th>
  <th data-field="TagName" data-sortable="true">Tag Name</th>
  <th data-field="CreatedBy"  data-sortable="true">Created By</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I'm trying to populate it using a PHP script s_displaytags.php. Currently im testing  it so the code is:

```
<?PHP
$ArrayValue = array();
$ArrayValue['SerialNumber'] = 1; 
$ArrayValue['TagName'] = 'test'; 
$ArrayValue['CreatedBy'] = 50; 

echo json_encode($ArrayValue);
?>
```

My HTML page loads but the table values do not get loaded.

I'm not using any functions at the  moment. It's just a plain PHP file returning one result row encoded s JSON.

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651402/bootstrap-table-data-url).

Comment: @sjsam - Thanks for the link. I saw this link and i'm also doing the same thing but it doesn't seem to work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @sjsam - I want the PHP script to directly populate the table. I don't want to create an intermediary json file since i'm already encoding the array to JSON

Answer (score 0):

so i just changed echo json_encode($ArrayValue); to echo json_encode(array($ArrayValue)); and it worked.